# can not FileWriter on anroid 11

Tags: android, filesystems, android-permissions, android-11

I used a code to write to the system root , Ever since **Android 11** was released this code can not write  my file on device and displays this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/Data/systemInfo: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

My code works on **Android 10** devices and below

this is my code :

```
 private void generateNoteOnRoot(String fileName,String sBody) {
    try {
        File systemFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/Data");
        if (!systemFile.exists())
        {
            systemFile.mkdirs();
        }
        File info = new File(systemFile, fileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(info);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("Authentication", "generateNoteOnRoot: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Before doing this process , i get the necessary access

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Dont try to write in or create your own subdirs of Android folder.

Comment: And check the return value of mkdirs() as now you try to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: @blackapps "AUTH/Data" Replace "Android/Data"?

Comment: ????? And why didnt you react and adapted the code around mkdirs?

Comment: it work , i change "Android/Data" to "nameFolder/Data"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
//Add below permission in manifest.xml and also don't forget to ask file write run time permission.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

//Add below attribute in manifest application tag
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"


//Write below code for file creation
private fun writeFile(fileData: String, fileName: String) {
val dir = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
            .toString() + "/" + "test"
    )
} else {
    File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString() + "/${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}/" + "test"
    )
}
dir.apply {
    if (!this.exists()) this.mkdir()
    File(this, "$fileName.txt").apply {
        if (!this.exists()) this.createNewFile()
        FileOutputStream(this).apply {
            write(fileData.toByteArray())
            close()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <provider
        android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

res/xml/provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```